# Подсветка папок командой ls

Tags: linux, centos, ls

Что означает папка подсвеченная желтым цветом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ["What do the different colors mean in ls?" askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls)

Comment: На моём мониторе это скорее зелёный...

Comment: спасибо, исправила, надо было забрать права на исолнение у группы других пользователей chmod o-x YouTrack

Comment: @ДианаКолосова, скорее ты хотел убрать право на запись — убирать право на исполнение довольно бессмысленное действие...

Answer (score 2):

согласно [`$ man dir_colors`](http://ru.manpages.org/dir_colors/5) каталоги в выводе программы *ls* расцвечиваются только в трёх случаях:

```
STICKY цвет
    Задаёт цвет, используемый для файлов с установленным закрепляющим (sticky) битом. 
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE цвет
    Задаёт цвет, используемый для каталогов с установленным битом sticky
    и доступный на запись другим.

    Синоним OWT. 
OTHER_WRITABLE цвет
    Задаёт цвет, используемый для каталогов без установленного бита sticky
    и доступный на запись другим.

    Синоним OWR.
```

(я, кстати, исправил в цитате забавную ошибку, которая присутствует и в оригинальной man-странице, и в переводе: в пунктах про STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE и OTHER_WRITABLE вместо sticky-бита упомянут бит выполнимости).

т.е., в вашем случае расцвечено имя каталога, у которого есть признак OTHER_WRITABLE — каталог доступен для записи всем и не установлен бит sticky.

---

по умолчанию расцветка должна быть синим шрифтом (42) на зелёном фоне (34):

```
$ dircolors -p | grep ^OTHER_WRITABLE
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

коды, обозначающие цвета, можно увидеть и в `$ man dir_colors` и в выводе программы *dircolors*, запущеной с опцией `-p`:

```
$ dircolors -p | grep -A 7 'Below are the color'
# Below are the color init strings for the basic file types. A color init
# string consists of one or more of the following numeric codes:
# Attribute codes:
# 00=none 01=bold 04=underscore 05=blink 07=reverse 08=concealed
# Text color codes:
# 30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white
# Background color codes:
# 40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white
```

---

но вообще на умолчальное поведение программы *ls* в отношении расцветки имён файлов/каталогов можно повлиять переменной окружения `LS_COLORS`. формирует её всё та же программа *dircolors*, обычно запускаемая где-нибудь в инициализационных файлах оболочки. например, в дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* — в `~/.bashrc`:

```
$ grep dircolors ~/.bashrc
    eval "`dircolors -b`"
```

например, после такой подмены имя упомянутого в вопросе каталога будет отображаться (в пределах текущего сеанса оболочки) чёрным шрифтом (30) на белом (или сером) фоне (47):

```
$ export LS_COLORS=$(echo $LS_COLORS | sed -r 's/ow[^:]+/ow=30;47/')
```

но, конечно, удобнее править не содержимое переменной окружения, а «исходную базу данных» (которую выдаёт команда `dircolors -p`): сохраните её в файл и передайте этот файл программе — `$ dircolors файл`. и она уже сформирует нужное значение для переменной окружения `LS_COLORS`.